# How do test Facebook deferred deep linking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, deep-linking

I've just put in the code to handle deferred deep linking, which is this:

```
[FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Received error while fetching deferred app link %@", error);
    }
    if (url) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}];
```

Now how do I test this? I've created an app in developer.facebook.com and inserted a custom scheme in my Info.plist. Then through Facebook App Ads helper, I tried sending deferred deep link but the code doesn't seem to run.

Here are my steps:

1) Send deferred deep link through Facebook App Ads Helper.
2) Click on notification in Facebook app on device.
3) Install app through Xcode in device.
4) Run the app

Is my steps wrong? And is there any other way to test Facebook deferred deep linking without Facebook App Ads Helper?

Comment: Perhaps by setting up a simple Open Graph object (HTML page), that includes App Links, and see if you land in the right place in your app if you click on a link to that document somewhere …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Comment: What were the debugging steps you did so far? Did you log the value of `url` yet? Did you implement `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` yet to even handle the deep link?